# Spark group data by date and zero fill data for id which is missing for the date

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have a spark dataset, I need to group the data by date and zero fill the data when id is not present for the date. I also need to transform the dataset for 30 days, given my end date is falling in 30th day in the original genre dataset, here is the sample dataset I am working with. What would be the best approach to make this transformation?

```
val genre = sc.parallelize(List(("id1", "2016-05-01", "action",0),
                                    ("id1", "2016-05-03", "horror",1),
                                    ("id2", "2016-05-03", "art",0),
                                    ("id2", "2016-05-04", "action",0))).
                               toDF("id","date","genre","score")
```

output

```
+---+----------+------+-----+
| id|      date| genre|score|
+---+----------+------+-----+
|id1|2016-05-01|action|    0|
|id1|2016-05-03|horror|    1|
|id2|2016-05-03|   art|    0|
|id2|2016-05-04|action|    0|
+---+----------+------+-----+
```

Desired output

```
+---+----------+------+-----+-----------
|      date| grouped                    |
+---+----------+------+-----+------------
|2016-05-01|[[id1,action,1],[id2,0, 0]] |
|2016-05-02|[[id1,0,0],[id2,0, 0]]      |
|2016-05-03|[[id1,horror,1],[id2,art,0]]|
|2016-05-04|[[id1,0,0],[id2,action, 0]] |
+---+----------+------+-----+-----------
```

Comment: Just a warning - its' not hard to achieve but in general structure like this won't scale. It might work on toy examples, but that's it.

Comment: what if you have more rows with id other than id1 and id2?

Comment: I would have another 100K id's. What I am really trying to understand is how to approach this problem. I understand this is easy to achieve in straight java code, given the spark driver and executor execution sequence, how do I achieve this?